# Trying to learn C++ constructors, why in this example is there a colon in the constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

```
template<class T>
Queue<T>::Queue(): frontPtr(NULL), backPtr(NULL), count(0)
{
}
```

Why is it `Queue():` and not just `Queue()`?

Comment: This will initialize frontPtr, backPtr and count the supplied values.

Comment: Whatever book you're using to learn C++ is doing a bad job if it doesn't explain this.

Comment: After a constructor is an optional initializer list, where member variables can be specified as a comma separated list of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colon indicates the `initializer list` of your constructor.
It enables you to value-initialize the member variables of your class.

The below is approximately similar (but less efficient than `Initializer List`):

```
template<class T>
Queue<T>::Queue()
{
 frontPtr = NULL;
 backPtr = NULL;
 count = 0;
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is that?

Comment: @DougSmith For further reading, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: @iolando it's not quite "similar" - there are implications about default construction of members.

Comment: @NikBougalis: indeed, i used "may", but i will correct the wording

Comment: Please note that the compiler may not use the order you specify initialization in the initializer list, but the function body can only be reordered if it does not change the semantics.

Comment: Indeed, the compiler definitely will not use the order you specify if that order does not coincide with the order in which they are declared.

Answer (score 4):

As others have commented, the `:` indicates the presence of an initializer list. You can find out more in your favorite C++ book or a number of good websites; A quick Google search gave me this article which seems to be well-written: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html.

If you want the short, executive summary of initializer lists, here  you go: The initializer list can contain calls to base-class constructors and calls to the constructors of member variables.

Why would you want such a thing? Well, many reasons.

---

*Note that the code is rather simplistic and contains a bit of silliness (e.g. the `Name` class). The purpose is just to show how initializer lists work, not to write fancy code or to leverage all possible C++ features.*

---

### Construction of a base class

Imagine that you have a base class which requires some parameters in order to be constructed. There is no other way to pass the parameters necessary to its constructor, since by the time the `{` that opens the body of the constructor "executes" (pardon the somewhat loose use of "executes" in this context) the base class has already been constructed:

```
class Name
{
    const char *name;

public:
    Base(const char *n)
    {
        name = n;
    }

    const char *getName() const
    {
        return name;
    }
};

class Derived : public Name
{
    int a;

public:
    Derived(int x)
        : Name("Derived")
    {
        a = y;
    }

    // Without the call to Name("Derived") in the constructor initializer
    // list how could you possibly initialize the base class here?
};
```

### Construction of a member that is a class instance

Similarly, perhaps you have class members that have constructors which require arguments. The problem is similar: where could you call those constructors to pass arguments and how? The answer is in the initializer list. Let's expand on our previous example:

```
class Name
{
    const char *name;

public:
    Base(const char *n)
    {
        name = n;
    }

    const char *getName() const
    {
        return name;
    }
};

class MyInt
{
    int value;

public:
    MyInt(int i)
    {
        value = i;
    }

    int getInt() const
    {
        return value;
    }
}

class Derived : public Name
{
    MyInt a;

public:
    Derived(int x)
        : Name("Derived"), a(x)
    {

    }

    // Without the call to a(x)  in the constructor initializer
    // list how could you possibly initialize that member variable 
    // here?
};
```

### Initialize member variables efficiently

When you manually set a value to a variable by putting it on the left-hand side of an assignment, you are actually not "initializing" it. You are performing an assignment instead.

This may be a somewhat esoteric difference, but it has many important implications. One of which (and not even the most important one) is performance.

Since in C the constructors of all base classes and all member variables must complete before your constructor body begins executing, this may mean a significant amount of work will be done in one of those constructors. All that work may then be lost when you assign a new value to one of those member variables.

So you can initialize member variables (regardless of their type) by passing the necessary values in a constructor initializer list. Let's rework our last example:

```
class Name
{
    const char *name;

public:
    Base(const char *n)
        : name(n)
    {
        // notice that at this point the member variable "name"
        // has already been initialized and can be accessed. 
    }

    const char *getName() const
    {
        return name;
    }
};

class MyInt
{
    int value;

public:
    MyInt(int i)
        : value(i)
    {
        // Again, note here that the variable "value" already contains
        // its value. We need not initialize it again.
    }

    int getInt() const
    {
        return value;
    }
}

class Derived : public Name
{
    MyInt a;

public:
    Derived(int x)
        : Name("Derived"), a(x)
    {

    }
};
```

Observe how we moved the initialization of things around a bit. Although our programs works identically, it now behaves a lot differently. To see why, let's add another class to the mix:

```
class Name
{
    const char *name;

public:
    Base(const char *n)
        : name(n)
    {
        // notice that at this point the member variable "name"
        // has already been initialized and can be accessed. 
    }

    const char *getName() const
    {
        return name;
    }
};

class MyInt
{
    int value;

public:
    MyInt(int i)
        : value(i)
    {
        // Again, note here that the variable "value" already contains
        // its value. We need not initialize it again.
    }

    int getInt() const
    {
        return value;
    }
}

class Example : public MyInt
{
    const char *type;

public:
    Example()
        : MyInt(0), type("default")
    {
    }

    Example(int x)
        : MyInt(x), type("custom")
    {
    }

    const char *getType() const
    {
        return type;
    }
}

class Derived : public Name
{
    Example a;
    Example b;

public:
    Derived(int x)
        : Name("Derived"), a(x)
    {

    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "This is an " << getName() << " instance" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "  a has a " << a.getType() << " value" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "    a=" << a.getInt() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "  b has a " << b.getType() << " value" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "    b=" << b.getInt() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Derived d;

    d.print(123);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

This:

```
template<class T>
Queue<T>::Queue(): frontPtr(NULL), backPtr(NULL), count(0)
{
}
```

achieves broadly the same end as:

```
template<class T>
Queue<T>::Queue()
{
    frontPtr = NULL;
    backPtr = NULL;
    count = 0;
}
```

with some important differences, including:

- with an initializer list, you don't construct and initialize as two separate operations;
- using an initializer list is the only way you can initialize `const` member variables.

Comment: Initializing is never separate from construction.  Did you mean *assign*?

Comment: No, I meant initializing, as in giving an object the initial value *you* want it to have. Further, a default constructor need not initialize POD data members, so although construction might guarantee an *object* is initialized itself, it doesn't guarantee all that object's data members will be.

Comment: The C++ Standard defines the term *initialize*.  Trying to force your  own, different, meaning on it is a terrible idea.  Doing so in an answer to someone who is trying to learn the language, is even worse.

Comment: The distinction is perfectly clear in the answer, which is written in English, and uses English words properly. This kind of melodramatic nitpicking at legal minutiae is not helpful, certainly not to a beginner, so please stop.

Comment: Look, beginners often confuse assignment and initialization.  And it causes them problems later, when they learn a rule that applies only to initialization, or they overload the assignment operator.  Your abuse of terminology only serves to prolong that pain.  I've given you adequate time to make a simple correction to your answer, but you've chosen to leave it incorrect.

Comment: You've had your say. "Incorrect" and "not my favored choice of word" are not equivalent. If you want to pointlessly bicker over minute shades of meaning in terminology, instead of over actual substance, you'll have to find someone else to humor you, I'm simply not interested in entertaining it.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths How about you come to [the Lounge](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec) so that we can show you how wrong you are?

Comment: "Correct" and "understandable to a certain degree" are not equivalent either. The answer might be written in plain English, but since it's talking about a specific topic (C++), certain semantics specific to that topic, *beyond* plain English, have to be accounted for. And with that semantics, initialization is done during object construction and not later. Your wording is *at least* unnecessarily imprecise and should be changed to not confuse the OP who is obviously a beginner.

Comment: I've already made my position clear, so if you want to debate this in some chat room, you can do it without me. The idea that POD members - which is what the OP actually has - are always initialized when created is wrong. The idea that class POD members are always initialized when the object itself is initialized is wrong. This odd suggestion that constructor initializer lists perform 'assignment' is wrong. For your 'correct' answer to actually be correct, you'd have to narrow the scope so far away from the actual question that the answer would in fact be misleading and wrong.